# How to declare not yet defined static variable in C

Tags: c, compiler-construction, static, extern

How to declare static variable prior to its definition? The use case is there is other global variable is using it before it is defined. And I don't want to move the definition to top.

Example code:

```
extern static int a; //compiler error, but I need to declare 'a' because it is used below by 'x'

typedef struct{
 int * dd;
}X;

static X x={&a}; //this variable needs to use 'a'

static int a=5; //this is where 'a' defined
```

Above code is compile error.

**=== Update ====**

Well, I found the solution myself. Just remove the `extern` keyword.

Comment: any reason can't reorder `static int a;` to top?

Comment: But why don't you just declare `static int a` at the top of your source file, and assign it later ? What would be the issue ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Static variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973162/static-variable)

Comment: Moderators, please ignore my flag for duplicate... On a second thought I don't think it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973162/static-variable

Comment: I want to know how it is done or if it is possible in C. It looks like a flaw if we cannot declare static as extern. What is the reason for this. I don't see problem if extern static is allowed.

Comment: @Spundun - you should be able to cancel the flag by clicking on "close" again.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam If I click flag again... it says "you have already raised this flag" and I don't see any close button. It's probably a privilege thing.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to use two [storage classes](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ansi_c/c_storage_classes.htm) at a time. Thats problematic. Use `static int a;`, and you can access it in your file, just make sure you are defining it above the code you are using it.

Comment: What is the reason extern static is forbidden? I think the reason is just because keyword extern and static is same type (storage classes), just like 'float int' is illegal. But I think 'extern static' is logical (it says there is static variable somewhere below in this file).

Comment: @dragon135 no, `extern` doesn't mean that. It means that "theres a variable named `a` in *some* file". And thats contradictory with `static` (which means "you can only access this variable from within this file").

Comment: @user3477950 it is not difficult to make additional rule so that it become like this: when compiler see 'extern' it means "there's a variable named a somewhere in some file" then after seeing keyword static it deduce "there's a variable named a somewhere in some file, and the file is actually this file".

Answer (score 1):

Read http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/43-file-scope-and-the-static-keyword/

In your example, the variable is declared static in the file scope. This means that it's available to all the code in the file.

In such a case it doesn't make sense to define it below the code that it uses. You should simply move it to the top of the file.

Also checkout [Forward declaring static C struct instances in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598369/forward-declaring-static-c-struct-instances-in-c) if you have a need to do this for some reason. May be the solution provided there could be adapted to fit your larger goal.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have two storage classes used on one single variable.
Doing this will flag an error